# Which TeX editors have an option to restrict search (find) to formulas?

Tags: editors, search

Once I had decided to change all the occurrences of the variable 'a' in formulas to 'b'. This was really a pain, because the search (find) tool had no option to limit the search of the letter a to formulas (whatever is between $ or $$ or \( or \[ ...). Which is why I am asking the question that is the title of this post.

Comment: On TeXstudio you can search change your search to whole words, but depending on how you wrote the formulas, this might not work...

Comment: IMHO the best solution is searching for the $ and \[ in the document and then look if in the equation finded there is the variable you are looking for. A more powerful, but more complex solution would be to import your .tex file as a string in WolframMathematica and then use the very powerful pattern matching capability of Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you @vipa for your work-arounds. The first one might be what I ended up doing, I don't remember exactly. For the second solution, I can't afford Mathematica. I much would prefer to use an editor which has the option I'm referring to.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoAlvesdaSilva . Does the whole word option consider _ and ^ as non-characters? Note that I still would get all the words 'a' in the text, and in English there's a lot.

Comment: @Arnaud yeah, it does not consider, and you're right, it probably would work better the other way around (switching from b's to a's)

Comment: @Arnaud The kernel of Mathematica from few months it's [free to use for developers and home users](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/). As front end for the kernel you can use [jupyter](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter)

Comment: Mathematica as the more complete string management tools that I know. You can easly create a search quest for your specific case.